# How do I remove the base of my laptop?

Tags: laptop-repair

How do I remove my laptop Base?

I've removed all the screws and the bottom nearly comes off, but there are these clip sort of things under where the battery should be that I've never seen before

My laptop is [NP-S3520-AD1UK](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP-S3520-A01UK)  It's the s3

[image: laptop ClipsA]

[image: LAptop ClipsB]

Comment: Samsung S3530 points to a mobile phone (image: http://www.gadgetfolder.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Samsung-S3530-Classic-Phone-1-300x300.jpg)... are you sure you've got the right information about your device?

Comment: Np s3520 It's the s3 series.

Comment: http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP-S3520-A01UK

Comment: Could you get a better picture of the clips you see? Thank you :)

Comment: It's quite difficult to link them as I'm on a mobile device.

Comment: It is difficult to see in your picture but are they tabs, and does that section simply slide out of the way?

Comment: I don't know..  I tried to push it to see maybe it slides but it doesn't.  I updated image links.

Comment: Try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScLCPolQ_oM - it's not the same model but the construction seems similar enough that it might help.